# When using tf.data in tensorflow for importing data from text files, memory used up

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I wanna use tensorflow to train an RNN and dense model, the data files are too big to input to memory, so I use `tf.data` module to generate batch data from files.

The data has 7 parts:

The 1st column:atom_length;

The 2nd column:relation_length;

The 3rd~the 1502 column: atom information

The 1503~2202 column: relation information

The 2203~3602 column: protein information

The 3603 column: protein_length

The last column: label

The code is following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time

NUM_EPOCHS=10
BATCH_SIZE=128

# default column types
default_column_value = [[0] for i in range(2)]
default_column_value.extend([[0.0] for i in range(3600)])
default_column_value.extend([[0] for i in range(2)])

# using tf.data module to generate the dataset and an iterator
filenames=tf.constant(["F:\\train1_2.txt"])
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda line: tf.decode_csv(
                line,         record_defaults=default_column_value)).repeat(NUM_EPOCHS).shuffle(buffer_size=1000).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

# stack specific columns, these are the data used for feeding to the placeholders
atom_length=next_element[0]
relation_length=next_element[1]
atom = tf.stack(next_element[2:1502],axis=1)
relation = tf.stack(next_element[1502:2202],axis=1)
protein_sequence = tf.stack(next_element[2202:3602],axis=1)
protein_length= next_element[-2]
labels = next_element[-1]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    tf.local_variables_initializer().run()
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    step=0
    epoch=1
    try:
        epoch_start_time=time.time()
        while(True):
            one_step_time=time.time()
            step=step+1
            if step%(int(489548//BATCH_SIZE+1))==0:
                print("epoch_used_time:"+str(time.time()-epoch_start_time))
                epoch_start_time=time.time()
                epoch+=1
            # generate the batch data used for training
            cur_atom_length_batch,cur_relation_length_batch,cur_protein_length_batch,cur_atom_batch,cur_relation_batch,cur_protein_sequence_batch,cur_labels_batch=sess.run(
                [atom_length,relation_length,protein_length,atom,relation,protein_sequence,labels])

            input_labels=sess.run(tf.one_hot(cur_labels_batch,depth=2,on_value=1,off_value=0))

        print("cur_atom_length_batch:",cur_atom_length_batch)
        print("cur_relation_length_batch:",cur_relation_length_batch)
        print("cur_atom_batch:",cur_atom_batch)
        print("cur_protein_length_batch:",cur_protein_length_batch)
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print("end of epochs.")
        pass
    finally:
        print('epoch time:',time.time()-epoch_start_time)
```

When I run the code, although the data was generated as batches, the local memory usage becomes higher and higher.

The train1_2.txt file is 3.75GB, and the 32GB local memory is almost used up even the 1st epoch training hasn't been finished! 
What could be the reason for this? What's the wrong with my code?

The environment I use this in is GTX1080 GPU, i7 processor, 32GB memory, Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you are adding new operations to the computational graph at every iteration. See this line:

```
input_labels=sess.run(tf.one_hot(cur_labels_batch,depth=2,on_value=1,off_value=0))
```

Calling `tf.one_hot` here will add a new operation to the graph. You add such an operation at every batch. What you want to do is place this operation outside your training loop and then evaluate its output inside your training loop instead of creating a new one, something like this:

```
one_hot = tf.one_hot(cur_labels_batch,depth=2,on_value=1,off_value=0)
# other necessary code here
while training:
    # ....
    other_ops_result, input_labels = sess.run([other_ops, one_hot])
```

Rule of thumb: don't call any `tf` namespace operations inside your training loop unless you explicitly want to add a new operation to your computational graph. Remember that once its added, it can not be removed, and will likely slow down your code and/or increase memory consumption unless its necessary.

Comment: It works! Thanks very much, I move the `tf.one_hot` to `labels=tf.one_hot(next_element[-1],depth=2,on_value=1,off_value=0)`,and it works.

Comment: @李成强 If the answer solved your problem, you can mark it accepted by clicking on the tickmark below the voting display.

Comment: cannot help feeling that you picked up the clue from our discussion and elaborated, collecting scores ultimately. If you knew the correct answer why didnt you post it instead of criticizing others' efforts to help? just out of curiosity.

Comment: @HSL I believe people's curiosity is an important reason that makes this a great Q&A site, so I am very glad you are curious too! As everyone hopes for the best answers possible, elaborating on answers that leave out some details or do not fully explain everything is totally OK! When I saw this question answered, I first checked the existing answer to see if it solves the problem. I left criticism in hopes of improving the answer. I never mean criticism as a personal attack.

Answer (score -1):

I have heard that this is a common error people encounter in their use of tensorflow. 
So I did my research..and
I'm wondering whether the two lines below in your code are working.

```
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
tf.local_variables_initializer().run()
sess.run(iterator.initializer)
```

1. Aren't the first two lines duplicate?
2. Isn't the following the correct implementation?

`session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`

3. Not completely sure here, but check this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9646). Could you try using

`feed_dict` parameter inside `sess.run()` instead of using another `tf` operation inside the `sess.run()`

Comment: `Dataset` iterator initialization is *not* the same as global/local variables initialization. This does not answer the question.

Comment: I am aware that the third line performs a separate function. Read carefully plz..

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! But this answer does not provide an answer to the question, as the initializaiton here has nothing to do with memory consumption.

Comment: I see. So you are sure of that but unsure of what is causing the problem. Then maybe the moderators would delete my post? Or shall I

Comment: This is not the full code. I just write the part used to generate data. The problem is found when I training my model first time, so I cut the part of generating data and found that the problem is just from here. But I don't know what's the problem is ...